# Set y a-xis to trange from 0 to 100 in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

How can I set my y-axis to range between 0 to 100?  This is my code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'], marker="*", label='Train accuracy', color='blue')
plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'], marker="o", label='Test accuracy', color='red')
plt.title('Plot' )
plt.ylabel('yaxis')
plt.xlabel('xaxis')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it would be to use `ylim`, as in:

```
...
plt.xlabel('xaxis')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.ylim(0,100).         # <== This is the relevant piece. 
plt.show()
```